# How to resolve "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: reactjs, debugging, npm

I have a Nodejs web app currently running on a server successfully. Now I'm trying to setup a local copy on my Development server.

I currently have Nodejs, NPM, react-mutation-mapper, mobx-react and bootstrap-react Installed just like what I have in production server however the error below occurs when I try to start node server.

error log:

```
Compiled with warnings.

Failed to parse source map from '/Users/maruwu/Desktop/project/react-now/node_modules/svg2pdf.js/dist/svg2pdf.min.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/maruwu/Desktop/project/react-now/node_modules/svg2pdf.js/dist/svg2pdf.min.js.map'

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in ./node_modules/svg2pdf.js/dist/svg2pdf.min.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '/Users/maruwu/Desktop/project/react-now/node_modules/svg2pdf.js/dist/svg2pdf.min.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/maruwu/Desktop/project/react-now/node_modules/svg2pdf.js/dist/svg2pdf.min.js.map'

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-now",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "mobx-react": "^7.5.3",
    "npm": "^8.19.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-mutation-mapper": "^0.8.56",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Project Folder..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAo11.png)

Whats could be causing this issue?

Comment: Have you tried installing the `svg2pdf` module separately? `npm i svg2pdf@version` where `version` can be used from your `package.json`

Comment: I tried to install it, but the same error is displayed

Comment: please provide your webpack configuration file along with your running script settings

Comment: Try uninstalling  react-mutation-mapper, mobx-react and bootstrap-react. Then delete the folders that where added when installing this packages inside your node_modules folder. Then install those packages again. Then try running your app. I had an error like yours when I had in installed redux and react-bootstrap. I solved it when I uninstalled my packages and installed them back.

Comment: I want to use the service provided by react-mutation-mapper.